# In NSIS, how to disable the ENTER key from the keyboard or prevent the consent button to get focus after clicking in the dialog window's text area?

Tags: winapi, focus, controls, nsis, enter

I have a NSIS installer that shows a picture of our product, a disclaimer in a text area, the decline button and the accept button.

I want to prevent a user to accept the offer by simply clicking the ENTER key on the keyboard.

Actually I've put a hidden button that does nothing as the default, so it doesn't trigger the install if ENTER is pressed.

The code of the hidden button from ressource hacker is:

> CONTROL "", 3, BUTTON, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 179, 272, 0, 0

Once the dialog windows is shown, the ENTER key doesn't trigger the accept button because the hidden button is the default and it's ok.

The issue is if the user clicks on the text area of the disclaimer and press ENTER, it triggers the install. (I've notices that the focus doesn't go to the accept button)

The code of the text area from ressource hacker is:

> CONTROL "", 1000, "RichEdit20A", ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL, 1, 134, 439, 79

Any ideas on how to prevent the trigger of the accept button by the ENTER key of the keyboard ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which page type is this? License? nsDialogs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify the default button in the dialog by sending [DM_SETDEFID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I used "SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${DM_SETDEFID} 4 0" but it doesn't work (4 is the id of the button I want to be default [different from the accept button])

Comment: The id of the button you added is 3 but changing it to 4 is not going to work, turns out NSIS has special enter handling for the license box and forces a click on the next button...